# Getting file path of a .vcf file with applescript (without user prompt)

Tags: applescript

Okay, So im trying to set a variable as the path to a .vcf file (Contact card file) without any user prompt, the file I need to set path of is on my desktop.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the relative path `path to desktop` which points to the desktop folder of the current user.

```
set myVCFCard to (path to desktop as text) & "card.vcf"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set p to (path to desktop as string) & "John Doe.vcf"
```